# Insert with Select give sql-error (SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505)(db2 z/os)

Tags: java, sql, db2-zos

I try to insert values from my java application and values from table1 into table2. I get the following error(db2 z/os):

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, SQLERRMC=1;DB2T.TSOZ360_WV_AUSGANG, DRIVER=3.66.46

PreparedStatement _prep = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DB2T.TABLE2 (column1, column2, column3 , column4, column5, column6) SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, column5, column6 FROM DB2T.TABLE1 WHERE column1 = ? column2 = ? AND column3 = ?");

_prep.setString(1,"HELLO");
_prep.setString(2,"H");
_prep.setString(3,"1234567890");
_prep.setString(4,"Hsdfdsffdssdfsdfd");
_prep.setLong(5,9876543210l);
_prep.setInt(6,1);
_prep.setInt(7,12345678);

Table1:
column1, column2, column3 , column4, column5, column6

Table2
column1, column2, column3 , column4, column5, column6
```

So I want to insert values I generated in the java application into TABLE2 and two values from TABLE1. Without import this two values into the application. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sql exception you got suggests that you're trying to insert 2 identical values into a column that accepts unique values (did you use this insert with the same parameter values more than once?).

However, your design is still bad so I would suggest that you  split your query/statement into a select and an insert (2 queries/statements instead of just 1). This would make the code more readable as well as easier to debug.
Second, you shouldn't use column names as parameters (?) in a PreparedStatement (a PreparedStatement is meant to be reusable, however, if column names are parameterized, the database can't reuse the statement).

This means that it's wrong  to do something like

```
          String sql = "SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, column5, column6 FROM DB2T.TABLE1 WHERE column1 = ? column2 = ? 

         _prep.setString(1, colName1);
         _prep.setString(2, colName2);
         ....
```

You will have to specify the column names in your query (select a,b,c from T where x=?). If they need to be obtained dynamically you can use string concatenation (this is potentially prone to sql injection  if you don't sanitize user input etc )

```
String dynamicColNames = getColumnNames();//just some method to get the names as one string
 String sql = "SELECT "+dynamicColNames + " FROM ....";//
 //dynamicColNames may contain col1, col2, col3 etc
```